# Angular / Three.js texture loading fail after ng build

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js

On local host texture shows normally, after compile doesnt show nothing

i dont know if im having a bad use of threejs or whats wrong, if i drop image on assest without any folder the texture apply to all the shape

[On local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjR24.png)

[After ng build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szj5h.png)

my code here

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
 })
export class AppComponent {
title = 'app';
constructor() {
 
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x000000)
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
window.addEventListener('resize',function () {
  let width = window.innerWidth;
  let height = window.innerHeight;
  renderer.setSize(width,height);
  camera.aspect=width/height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});
const ambientlighting = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xff0080,0.1)
const lighting = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff,1.5, 75)
lighting.position.y = 20;
lighting.position.x = 20;
lighting.position.z = 20;


const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('./assets/textures/descarga.png');

const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x96b0bc, map:texture /*wireframe:true*/ } 
 );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, /*cubematerials/**/material );
scene.add( cube,ambientlighting,lighting);

camera.position.y = 2;
camera.position.x = 2;
camera.position.z = 2;
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
controls.update();
const animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
controls.update();
cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your Network tab in the developer tools? Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: i dont have any error in dev tools, i guess its something with threejs and typescript folder /assest

Comment: in build i have an error, thanks 
*/*/*/*/**


Access to image at 'file:///C:/Users/David%20Vargas/Desktop/1/app/dist/app/assets/descarga.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.*/*/*/*

now idk how to access it

Comment: may if i change the route

Comment: I see what’s happening. You need to serve your build files through a localhost. See here: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: After publish on hosting/server it works, error is in my workspace because Chrome needs a "special Permission to acces to my folders"same in edge the solution was there ('https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1195078/How-to-fix-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supporte')